# Eclipse: AL lib: (EE) DoReset: Failed to check format support: 0x80070057

Tags: java, eclipse, windows, adt

today I installed a windows movie maker 2012 on my windows 7. After this, my eclipse started to throw this: **AL lib: (EE) DoReset: Failed to check format support: 0x80070057**

Also I noticed that wmm 2012 came in some windows live essentials package, which as I investigated installed some directx components and windows update without even asking me about it(I set it to install only wmm 2012 in the windows live essentials package).

Also, it looks like this "warning/exception?" doesnt harm, or I just didnt notice anything unusual in my application behaviour.

I tried to uninstall everything that came with this package, tried to rebuild my project, tried to reinstall eclipse(Im using ADT bundle) and even used the windows recovery thing(which recovers the system to the latest recovery point) - nothing helped.

So, it just pops up in eclipse console window when Im launching my desktop application. Color of this message is red.

**AL lib: (EE) DoReset: Failed to check format support: 0x80070057**

Please, if anyone knows something about it - post here, this thing is just too annoying :(

Thanks.

**EDIT**
I solved my problem!
Good thing I had somewhere deep in my mind that 0x80070057 is related to sound! So after a bit of searching for the reason - I clicked on control panel -> sound, and it told me that there is something wrong with sound drivers and asked me If I want to fix it. So I accepted it, and woohoo this "warning/exception?" disappeared :D:D:D